# everything working except rails. rails -v returns a long message. Gem::LoadError + other stuff

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rvm, homebrew

I'm so frustrated. I just wiped my computer clean for a new start, after trying for several days to get rails installed. I followed this tutorial http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/#step-4

It actually worked too, but when I woke up the next morning, I got this new "error"

Everything seemed to be working. I installed xcode, homebrew first, and then installed RVM. and it all seems to be working. I have ruby 2.0.0, but when I type "rails -v" after installing I get the following:

```
$ rails -v
/Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find minitest (~> 4.2) amongst [actionmailer-4.0.0, actionmailer-3.2.13, actionpack-4.0.0, actionpack-3.2.13, activemodel-4.0.0, activemodel-3.2.13, activerecord-4.0.0, activerecord-3.2.13, activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3, activeresource-3.2.13, activesupport-4.0.0, activesupport-3.2.13, arel-4.0.0, arel-3.0.2, atomic-1.1.10, builder-3.1.4, builder-3.0.4, bundler-1.3.5, bundler-unload-1.0.1, erubis-2.7.0, hike-1.2.3, i18n-0.6.4, i18n-0.6.1, journey-1.0.4, json-1.8.0, mail-2.5.4, mime-types-1.23, multi_json-1.7.7, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.5.2, rack-1.4.5, rack-cache-1.2, rack-ssl-1.3.3, rack-test-0.6.2, rails-4.0.0, rails-3.2.13, railties-4.0.0, railties-3.2.13, rake-10.1.0, rdoc-3.12.2, rubygems-bundler-1.2.0, rubygems-update-1.8.24, rvm-1.11.3.8, sprockets-2.10.0, sprockets-2.2.2, sprockets-rails-2.0.0, thor-0.18.1, thread_safe-0.1.0, tilt-1.4.1, treetop-1.4.14, tzinfo-0.3.37] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:777:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:780:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1232:in `gem'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Please help. I've been trying for three days and even completely reset my computer. and I am so close. What do I need to do?

Comment: Try run `gem install rails` again

Comment: how about `rvm use 2.0.0 --default`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, step back and take a deep breath. The tutorial kind of does a disservice because it doesn't show you the individual steps for RVM rubies, gems and gemsets, but rather does it in a single command.

First, check which ruby(s) you have installed with this command

```
rvm list
```

this will print out what you have installed, like this

```
   ruby-1.9.3-p385 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

now it looks like you have 2.0.0, lets make it the default ruby

```
rvm use 2.0.0 --default
```

now lets create a gemset called `rails-3.2.13`, this is where we will install the rails gem

```
rvm gemset create rails-3.2.13
```

lets make this gemset the currently used and default gemset

```
rvm gemset use rails-3.2.13 --default
```

time to install rails

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.13
```

Now when you type `rails -v` it should show this version of rails. Also, because we set the default to `ruby 2.0.0` and the gemset to `rails-3.2.13`, each time you open a new terminal it will be same ruby and rails version.

Take a look at the [RVM website and docs](https://rvm.io/) for the other thousand things rvm can do. Good luck

Comment: Thanks all, Sorry I didn't respond to all this, somehow I got it figured out.